# Redirect url with hash in Next JS

Tags: javascript, redirect, next.js

In Next JS I need to have a redirect that happens for a urls that include a "#"

For example /contact#support
Should redirect to /contact-us/support

**Attempt #1**

```
{
"source": "/contact#support",
"destination": "/contact-us/support",
"permanent": true
},
```

**Attempt #2** using regex matching

```
{
"source": "/:slug(^contact#support$)",
"destination": "/contact-us/support",
"permanent": true
},
```

I'm not sure if something like this just isn't possible. I haven't been able to find any other forum posts that go over this same scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using client side redirect

```
const path = window.location.pathname;
const hash = window.location.hash;
const url = path + hash;

switch (url) {
case '/contact#support':
    window.location.replace('/contact-us/support');
    break;
default:
    window.location.replace('/');
}
```